# How to kill connection with between user and server?

Tags: tcp, server, connection, kill

For the first connection my proxy server direct user to server1 and then I want to redirect him to server2 but firstly I have to kill connection. If I use tcpkill it kills all further connections from this ip, and user can't get response from the server. How can I kill during connection and be able to create new after next user's request?

Comment: This looks like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). You have some unknown problem X and you think the solution to this is that you need to kill the connection. I doubt that this is actually the proper way to solve the problem but unfortunately your real problem X is unknown. It would be more useful to at least present problem X as context to your "solution" Y so that one can help you to solve the real problem.

Comment: I've already tried to ask about X problem, but no one could help me. I want to use iptables to redirect bad users after analyzing  from server1 to server2 But if I change some rules in iptables they  will not take effect because the connection is already established. Thus I want to kill this connection.

Comment: This looks like another level of XY problem. iptables is not really a suitable tool for redirection since it works at the packet layer while redirection is done at the application layer.

Comment: I want to make this system https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/89312/host-based-security-architecture-for-web-server-network

Comment: I was under the assumption that you want to do a HTTP redirect but it looks like you want to forward new connections of a client to a different IP address than the previous ones at the IP level. I'm not sure what information you have about the connection but tcpkill is not restricted to match by IP address but you could also match by source port, destination port ... I think in order to get better help you probably need to describe your setup in more detail  (i.e. have enough context) - and [security.se] might maybe be more appropriate for this kind of questions.